# Limitar numero de datos a insertar en base de datos mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Inserto un nombre desde un formulario a una base de datos que representa los participantes de un taller. En el taller solo hay espacio para 30 personas y trate de limitar eso con la funcion COUNT(*). Mi problema es que el formulario sigue enviando datos aun que la base de datos ya tenga 30 entradas. Gracias por su ayuda.

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass", "base");
if($link === false){
  die("ERROR: No se puede conectar. " . mysqli_connect_error());
 }

 $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['name']);

 $res = mysqli_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM `taller1` "); 
 $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);

 if($row['cnt']<30){
   $sql = "INSERT INTO taller1 (name) VALUES ('".$name."')";
   if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
     echo "Su registro se ha realizado correctamente.";
   }
   else{
     echo "ERROR: no se pudo añadir $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
   }
 }
 else{
   echo "Taller lleno";
 }

 mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: tu primer error es que estas mezclando drivers primero usas mysql y luego mysqli eso es incorrecto o es uno o el otro pero no ambos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te coloco un ejemplo, ya solo debes adaptarlos a tus necesidades:

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "demo");
$res = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM alumnos ");

$fila = mysqli_num_rows($res);

printf($fila);

if($fila <= 2){
  $sql = "INSERT INTO alumnos (nombre, edad, sexo) VALUES ('dato1', 34, 'dato1')";
  mysqli_query($link, $sql);
}
else{
  echo "Taller lleno";
}
```

Te hago los siguientes comentarios

> 1. Para leer el número de filas hago uso del método mysqli_num_rows, la cual recibe como parámetro la variable que contiene la query
> 2. Gracias a la función que te menciono en el punto 1, ya no necesito hacer un count de los registros; basta con que haga un select * from
>      tabla y va a funcionar

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvio mucho

Comment: En estos casos, si no se van a utilizar los datos de la consulta es mejor hacer un count() siempre, traer los datos para desecharlos es un desperdicio de recursos y se incrementa el desperdicio si ademas utilizas * en el SELECT... El OP lo tenia correcto pero no estaba pasando $link en el query.